# Check Current Environment of Drupal Instance

Tags: 7

Is there a built-in way to check what environment Drupal is running in?

I'm coming from an environment where you would do something like

```
if Rails.env.production?
  render partial: "shared/google_analytics"
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: No, there's no built-in way. Either set environment-specific vars through settings.php, or through web server config

Comment: @MPD: I want to include google analytics if the site is running in production mode. That way analytics is there in production, but not in development.

Comment: @Clive: Okay. I guess I'll have to do that then. I was hoping Drupal had something like that built in

Comment: @MPD: The code I wrote is Ruby. It's checking Rails' current environment, and if it's production, it's rendering out the `app/views/shared/_google_analytics.html.erb` file.

Comment: Deployment's not one of Drupal's strongest points at the moment (things are getting much better in D8). Even in D8, though, I don't recall seeing anything equivalent to Symfony's [environments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html), so it might be that it's just not in the roadmap.